# Userform textboxes are blank after reopening excel file

Tags: excel, vba, userform

Currently I have a userform with multiple page aka `MultiPage`and each of those `MultiPage`has `Textboxes` which will take in inputs from user and each of those pages has a `Back` , `Next` button and specifically the next Button helps transferring the values from the Userform to the excel sheet called `"DoNotPrint-Setup"`.

[image]

```
  Private Sub btnNext2_Click()


    If cbClient = "" Or tbProject.Value = "" Or tbNumber.Value = "" Or tbRevision.Value = "" Or tbDate.Value = "" Or tbPMOC.Value = "" Or tbPMOE.Value = "" Or tbClientE.Value = "" Or tbClientN.Value = "" Or tbClientP.Value = "" Or tbClientSA1.Value = "" Or tbClientSA2.Value = "" Then
    If MsgBox("Form is not complete. Do you want to continue?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo) <> vbYes Then
    Exit Sub
    End If

End If

    With Sheets("DoNotPrint - Setup")
        .Range("C7").Value = Me.cbClient.Text
        .Range("C8").Value = Me.tbProject.Text
        .Range("C9").Value = Me.tbNumber.Text
        .Range("C10").Value = Me.tbRevision.Text
        .Range("C11").Value = Me.tbDate.Text
        .Range("C12").Value = Me.tbPMOC.Text
        .Range("C13").Value = Me.tbPMOE.Text
        .Range("C14").Value = Me.tbClientN.Text
        .Range("C15").Value = Me.tbClientE.Text
        .Range("C16").Value = Me.tbClientP.Text
        .Range("C17").Value = Me.tbClientSA1.Text
        .Range("C18").Value = Me.tbClientSA2.Text
End With
Me.MultiPage1.Value = 2

ending:
End Sub
```

This is what I have for Initialization process of the file below:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    WizardProp.MultiPage1.Value = 0
    Me.MultiPage1.Style = fmTabStyleNone

End Sub
```

And I have a Finish button at the end which will hide the Userform

```
Private Sub BtnFinish_Click()
    Me.Hide
End Sub
```

So right now it takes the output from the userform and inputs the values into the excel cell, but when I close the excel file the Userform textboxes are blank when its reopened. So is there a way to take the values in the excel cells and apply it to the Userform textboxes when Userform is reopened??

Comment: You just need to reverse your equations from your click event to your initialize event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to create logic for

- A) Determining if you are opening a fresh file (I recommend using a check to find the last row on your data sheet, as that's pretty simple... that is if you use  a master file which contains no values)
- B) Once you have checked A, then your initialize does one of two things (think If statement):  1) opens up blank, 2) opens up with values

Now the first part of B is pretty simple, you've already got that; the second part will just be inverting your With Statement:

```
With Sheets("DoNotPrint - Setup")
    .Range("C7").Value = Me.cbClient.Text
    .Range("C8").Value = Me.tbProject.Text
    .Range("C9").Value = Me.tbNumber.Text
    .Range("C10").Value = Me.tbRevision.Text
    .Range("C11").Value = Me.tbDate.Text
    .Range("C12").Value = Me.tbPMOC.Text
    .Range("C13").Value = Me.tbPMOE.Text
    .Range("C14").Value = Me.tbClientN.Text
    .Range("C15").Value = Me.tbClientE.Text
    .Range("C16").Value = Me.tbClientP.Text
    .Range("C17").Value = Me.tbClientSA1.Text
    .Range("C18").Value = Me.tbClientSA2.Text
End With
```

Becomes (when embedded in the Initiate routine):

```
With Sheets("DoNotPrint - Setup")
    Me.cbClient.Text = .Range("C7").Value
    '... 
    Me.tbClientSA1.Text = .Range("C17").Value
    Me.tbClientSA2.Text = .Range("C18").Value
End With
```

Comment: Regarding part A, I haven't done finding the last row before so would I need to use Range.Find? https://www.excelcampus.com/vba/find-last-row-column-cell/

Comment: @GoldFusion See: [Ron de Bruin's breakdown of last row/column, etc.](https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win005.htm)

Comment: Does this need to have a separate macro or can be tied to the "userform_initialize"?

Comment: @GoldFusion you can have separate lines in your userform initialize, inclusive of finding the last row, so you can store and use that information when initializing the form.